# Vim Ack search highlight

Tags: vim

I'm using MacVim with the ack Plugin (https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim). I've updated my Plugins and Vim itself, and now when I search for something, the highlight color of the search bar is in turquoise (see screenshot), and you can't really read the text.

I've already read through ack help and some threads, but I couldn't find a option where I can adjust the color.

How can I change it back to the old color?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the cause of your issue, but Vim added a new highlighting group in patch [8.0.0641](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/2102035488e80ef6fd5038ed15d21672712ba0f6), which is called `QuickFixLine`.

The default colors which were chosen seemed to make the current entry in the quickfix window difficult to read with several colorschemes. An [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1780) was opened on the bug tracker of the Vim repository, and the highlighting group was linked to `Search` in patch [8.0.0653](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/c768a208ca8e0e0fec900c18d5d9a593357ad793).

So, if your Vim version is between `8.0.0641` and `8.0.0652`, you may need to update Vim again to a newer version.

If you can't update immediately, then maybe you could temporarily link `QuickFixLine` to `Search`:

```
:hi! link QuickFixLine Search
```

Comment: You're right, my version is 8.0.648 (134). There is no update so far for anything > 8.0.652, so i tried your fix, and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: This is now fixed, can confirm it for version 8.0.1098 (137)